# Match everything except a specific string

Tags: python, regex

I have looked at lots of posts with similar title but I have found nothing that works with python or even this site: https://regex101.com

How can I match everything but a specific text?

My text:

```
1234_This is a text Word AB

Protocol  Address          ping
Internet  1.1.1.1            - 
Internet  1.1.1.2            25 
Internet  1.1.1.3            8 
Internet  1.1.1.4            - 

1234_This is a text Word BCD    
Protocol  Address          ping
Internet  2.2.2.1            10 
Internet  2.2.2.2            -
```

I want to match `Word \w+` and then the rest until the next 1234.
So the result should be (return groups marked in `()`):

```
(1234_This is a text (Word AB))(

Protocol  Address          ping
Internet  1.1.1.1            - 
Internet  1.1.1.2            25 
Internet  1.1.1.3            8 
Internet  1.1.1.4            - 

)(1234_This is a text (Word BCD)(    
Protocol  Address          ping
Internet  2.2.2.1            10 
Internet  2.2.2.2            - )
```

The first part is easy as: `matches = re.findall(r'1234_This is a text (Word \w+)', var)`
But the next part I am unable to achieve.
I have tried negative lookahead:
`^(?!1234)` but then it matches nothing any more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/6KTZO7/1)

```
(1234[\w ]+(Word \w+))((?:(?!1234)[\s\S])*)
```

Using the `s` modifier you can use the following.
[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/6KTZO7/2)

```
(1234[\w ]+(Word \w+))((?:(?!1234).)*)
```

---

### Explanation

- `(1234[\w ]+(Word \w+))` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `1234` Match this literally
  - `[\w ]+` Match one or more word characters or spaces
  - `(Word \w+)` Capture the following into capture group 2

    - `Word` Match this literally (note the trailing space)
    - `\w+` Match any word character one or more times
- `((?:(?!1234)[\s\S])*)` Capture the following into capture group 2

  - `(?:(?!1234)[\s\S])*` Match the following any number of times ([tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat/37343088#37343088))

    - `(?!1234)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match
    - `[\s\S])*` Match any character any number of times

Comment: Thanks that worked. Wow, this negative lookahead stuff is still really hard to get my head around...

Comment: @mrCarnivore It's basically saying this: at this position in the string, do the next characters match `1234`? If so stop matching, otherwise continue matching.

Comment: What is the `[\s\S]` for? You can replace it with `.` (matching any char). However, `.*` does not work, although I would expect it to.

Comment: @mrCarnivore you can use `.` if you turn on the single line modifier in regex. `.` doesn't match newline characters, which is why `[\s\S]` is used. `[\s\S]` says to match any whitespace or non-whitespace character (in other terms, match any character).

Comment: Ok, I think I get it: you specify what you don't want with `(?!1234)`, however in the same capturing group you do also need to specify what you _do_ want. That is why you have to either add `.` or `\s\S`. The quantifier for the whole part comes after the brackets...

Comment: I've added an edit using `.` with the `DOTALL` modifier. If you click on the link I added in the explanation ([tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat/37343088#37343088)), Wiktor explains well how this method works. You're pretty much correct though, I want to match any character unless it'll be `1234`; then I don't want to match.

Comment: Thanks. The `.` itself I fully understand (I only didn't get at first that `\s\S` is also an extended version of every char). However, the necessity at this point was unclear to me as I thought that specifying what I do not want with the negative lookahead would be enough to return anything. But I now realize that negative lookahead itself does not suffice.

Comment: @mrCarnivore lookaheads and lookbehinds don't actually match a character to consume them: They're basically assertions. This means it'll ensure that at *X* position (whatever *X* represents), ensure *Y* does or does not match (where *Y* is some condition)

Answer (score 1):

As you stated out:

> I want to match Word \w+ and then the rest until the next 1234.

Do you want something like this ?

```
import re
pattern=r'((1234_This is a text) (Word\s\w+))((\n?.*(?!\n\n))*)'
string="""1234_This is a text Word AB

Protocol  Address          ping
Internet  1.1.1.1            -
Internet  1.1.1.2            25
Internet  1.1.1.3            8
Internet  1.1.1.4            -

1234_This is a text Word BCD
Protocol  Address          ping
Internet  2.2.2.1            10
Internet  2.2.2.2            -"""

match=re.finditer(pattern,string,re.M)
for find in match:
    print("this is group_1 {}".format(find.group(1)))
    print("this is group_3 {}".format(find.group(3)))




    print("this is group_4 {}".format(find.group(4)))
```

output:

```
this is group_1 1234_This is a text Word AB
this is group_3 Word AB
this is group_4 

Protocol  Address          ping
Internet  1.1.1.1            -
Internet  1.1.1.2            25
Internet  1.1.1.3            8
Internet  1.1.1.4            
this is group_1 1234_This is a text Word BCD
this is group_3 Word BCD
this is group_4 
Protocol  Address          ping
Internet  2.2.2.1            10
Internet  2.2.2.2            -
```

Comment: No, this is not the result I want. I want the original texts returned and split into different capturing groups (the ones I have marked in my question). Beware: There is also one nested capturing group!

Comment: Thank you. That also works. However, the other solution is a little more robust as it will also work if there is not a empty line in between the data blocks.